# On-prem Deployment issues with Deployment script on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508] Power Shell 5.1

Tags: azure, azure-devops, windows-10

I am attempting to do an on prem deployment from AZ Devops to a local box. Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508] Using Deployment Groups feature. I checked the box for use Personal Access Token as in the image yet it asks for a password. The user name and password I give it is some how unacceptable even though is an administrator. Is that different than

[image]

"NT Authority\System"

Which user name and pwd should I use?
Shouldn't it bypass prompt for usr/pwd and substitute PAT?
I have a PAT in my azure devops. Do I need to enter before running script?
Should I do an AZ-Logon First?

Then when i run in Admin Window prompt for user name and pwd come in to play. It wants some other user / pwd. I gave it an Admin usr pwd on box.

My Powershell is Version ------- 5.1.19041.1

I tried some more the Flow of the script has changed i wish I had the old script text for comparison. It seems different as it is now more descriptive:

Enter a valid value for User account to use for the service.
[image]

So I have tried putting

1. BM-SERVER\LocalSystem
2. BM-SERVER\Local System
3. BM-SERVER\markd
4. BM-SERVER\Local Service
5. BM-SERVER\LocalService
   6.BM-SERVICE\Network Service

All but 3. respond : `Enter a valid value for User account to use for the service`
3. responds with: `Invalid windows credentials entered. Try again or ctrl-c to quit`
In this case I know it is valid account name and pwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the prompt carefully and when i let it use the default account there was no need to enter an account or password. It worked and my deployment task is done!

Short form just press Enter when prompted for an account

Comment: Great to see your issue is solved. Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) once you can, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. Ps: It looks similar to my last paragraph...

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the same issue on my side. Please check whether your password is right, case-sensitivity?

[image]

I use the my Admin account (lancel, which I use to login the Windows System) and corresponding password when entering User Account, and it works.

Also you can choose to Press **Enter** to use `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` instead of local account as `Account for Service` if the local account keeps throwing errors. It's also a widely recommended way, you can feel free to use default `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.